# How to decrease starting time b/w two drawable animations?

Tags: android, android-animation

I have prepared no.of drawable animations for my application.All are working fine.When application launch drawable animation will be start and i have two buttons(next and previous) in same activity.When i click on next or previous button animation will be change.It is working fine.But when i click on next or previous button it is taking time to changing animations.This my code,

```
mImgLetter.clearAnimation();
        Log.d("before clear","------");
        mImgLetter.setBackgroundResource(resID);
        Log.d("after clear","------");
        mImgLetter.post(new Runnable() {

            public void run() {

                loadingAnimation = (AnimationDrawable) mImgLetter
                        .getBackground();
                loadingAnimation.start();
            }
        });
```

How to decrease starting time b/w two drawable animations when i click on buttons.Please help me.

Logcat is,

```
02-21 17:52:57.278: D/before clear(813): ------
02-21 17:52:57.337: D/dalvikvm(813): GC freed 285 objects / 12160 bytes in 47ms
02-21 17:52:57.568: D/dalvikvm(813): GC freed 255 objects / 13568 bytes in 50ms
02-21 17:52:57.798: D/dalvikvm(813): GC freed 24 objects / 1016 bytes in 49ms
02-21 17:52:58.018: D/dalvikvm(813): GC freed 24 objects / 1016 bytes in 48ms
02-21 17:52:58.808: D/dalvikvm(813): GC freed 24 objects / 1024 bytes in 52ms
02-21 17:52:59.447: D/dalvikvm(813): GC freed 24 objects / 1016 bytes in 327ms
02-21 17:53:00.127: D/dalvikvm(813): GC freed 26 objects / 1160 bytes in 51ms
02-21 17:53:00.358: D/dalvikvm(813): GC freed 24 objects / 1032 bytes in 49ms
02-21 17:53:01.138: D/dalvikvm(813): GC freed 26 objects / 1552 bytes in 48ms
02-21 17:53:01.678: D/after clear(813): ------
```

GC will taking lot of time.Let me know how to reduce GC time.